# break out of iframe to new url in same domain on button click

Tags: javascript, .net, events, iframe

What's the correct javascript syntax for breaking out of an iframe to a separate url? I.e. I have a page inside an iframe with a form on it, after submitting that form I'd like to redirect to a separate page on the site (same domain) but open it in the parent window instead of inside the iframe. This is what I've tried:

```
protected void ReplacePageClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = "Contact.aspx";

    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

    cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "RedirectScript", "top.document.location.href = " + url, true);
    //top.document.parent.location.href?
    //top.document.location.replace?
    //window.parent.location?
    //window.top.location.href?
    //window.top.location.replace?
    //parent.window.location.href?
    //top.location.href?

    // the below works, so we know it's able to register javascript
    //cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", "alert('hello')", true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
top.location = "url"
```

or

```
top.location.replace("url")
```

Change top for parent depending on how high you want to go in the hierarchy.

I am assuming you are using IE and see "Access denied" in your console (F12) due to cross domain security blocking "access" to a page from another domain. This will happen if the page in the iFrame does not have the same origin as the parent page

Try

```
window.open("url","_top")
```

The better solution is to target the form to _top in the first place. That the browser will likely allow since the user actually clicks on something to load a new url somewhere

Comment: window.open("url","_top") works fine, thank you! The pages are on the same domain so there was no access denied error.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't. I could put the entire source code up somewhere if you'd like to have a look?